# Android DatePicker Dialog on Lenovo k900 not working properly

Tags: android, datepicker

I am trying to pick up the date of birth using a date picker. I am using the following code : -

```
new DatePickerDialog(SignUpOne.this, date, 1950,01,
                            01).show();
```

I have tested on HTC ONE S, and Galaxy S4 and Samsung Galaxy Grand Quattro. They are all showing the initial date as 1950,01,01

But when i am testing it with Lenovo K900 running Android 4.2.1 and it keeps showing the initial date as 1989-01-01.

Is there an alternative to set the initial date.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use setMinDate() method of DatePicker, e.g.:

```
Calendar minPickerDate = Calendar.getInstance();
minPickerDate.set(Calendar.YEAR, 1900);
picker.setMinDate(minPickerDate.getTimeInMillis());
```